# Smooch- Customize chat interface window

Tags: ios, sdk, smooch

So this time i want to integrate the [Smooch](https://smooch.io) api to make ios chat application.

I have integrated the smooch SDK successfully and with `[smooch show]` method, it opens the chat window.

Does anyone one know how to customize this window? The methods in documentation to customize user interface is limited to change navigation color and text of button. Let's say i want a background image in my chat window. So how can we customize this whole window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the docs are correct, only limited customization is possible at this time (source: I work at Smooch). There are plans to allow greater customizability in the future.

If all you wanted was to change the background color / background image though, you might be able to walk the view hierarchy of the conversation view controller and find a good place to put your view. I haven't tested this code, so it may not work, but this is the general idea:

```
UIViewController* conversationVC = [Smooch newConversationViewController];
[conversationVC.view addSubview:myBackground];
[conversationVC.view sendSubviewToBack:myBackground];
```

Comment: Thanks. Hope to see this update soon. BTW your suggestion is not working :-).

Comment: @michaels any update on customisation options? We are looking for options to customize Smooch chat in Android and iOS too.